# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError на одной машине, на второй все ok

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, jboss, redhat

Собираем веб приложение app.war 
Разворачиваю на своей машине - получаю ошибку.
Разворачивает сосед всё отлично работает.

Меняю зависимость guava c 13 на 19 у меня всё начинает работать, но у второго сотрудника появляется та же самая ошибка, что была у меня с 13 guava.

Берем один и тот же app.war, один и тот же сервер Jboss EAP 6 (полностью скопировал папку jboss у соседа). У меня Fedora 24 у него Fedora 23.

У коллег работающих на Windows работает аналогично, как у соседа на 23 Fedora. Буду благодарен любым, самым смелым предположениям.

```
Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheLoader;)Lcom/google/common/cache/LoadingCache;
at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceLibraryFactoryImpl.<init>(ResourceLibraryFactoryImpl.java:64) [richfaces-core-4.5.14.Final.jar:4.5.14.Final]
at org.richfaces.application.DefaultModule.configure(DefaultModule.java:75) [richfaces-core-4.5.14.Final.jar:4.5.14.Final]
at org.richfaces.application.ServicesFactoryImpl.init(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:60) [richfaces-core-4.5.14.Final.jar:4.5.14.Final]
at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.createFactory(InitializationListener.java:110) [richfaces-core-4.5.14.Final.jar:4.5.14.Final]
at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStart(InitializationListener.java:69) [richfaces-core-4.5.14.Final.jar:4.5.14.Final]
at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:167) [richfaces-core-4.5.14.Final.jar:4.5.14.Final]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2166) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:303) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:288) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:601) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:370) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас в проекте несколько версий библиотек, которые между собой конфликтуют.

Попробуйте запустите приложение с флагом `-verbose:class` выведется список загруженных классов и название `jar` файла откуда они берутся.

Далее, в `maven` посмотрите, какие зависимости используют данный `jar` архив. Это делается командой `dependency:tree`. Ну а дальше, просто исключаете, данную зависимость.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Наверное и через verbose:class получилось бы узнать из какого jar подтягивается guava. Но проблему решил  не успев увидеть Ваш ответ. У меня никак не получалось отлогировать 'CacheBuilder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()', потомучто ошибка выпадала практически в самом начале. Но потом добавил блок статической инициализации в ejb синглтон и лог отработал. Оказалось guava подхватывалась из sisu-guava. Исключили тэгом <exclusion> и всё заработало.